# Using $_GET variable in URL with ?id= from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to redirect a user to the previous page (topic.php) when they successfully submit a new post. That's easy:

```
header("Location: viewtopic.php?id=" . $topicid . ");
```

I may be going about this the wrong way, but on success, i want them to be redirected automatically to the address above and display a success message.

Some of my postreply.php

```
$result = $database->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    header('Location: /community/viewtopic.php?id=' . $topicid . '+status=success');
}else {
    echo "Query failed" . print_r($sql);
}
```

This is on the viewtopic.php:

```
$statusmsg = $_GET['status'];

  if (isset($statusmsg)) {
if ($statusmsg === "success") {
  $statusmsg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                  <strong>Success!</strong> Your post was submitted.
                </div>';
}else {
  $statusmsg = "";
}
  }
```

Understandably, php thinks the `+status=success` is part of the query to fetch the data from the database, thus results in a MySQL error.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `&` instead of `+` when passing parameters from the url to the `$_GET` super-global in PHP.

So, you need to change`'+status=success'` to `'&status=success'`

Also, as noted in the comment you should always validate user input sent via `$_POST`/`$_GET`.

in your case, you can use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
    $statusmsg = filter_var($_GET['success'], FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING);

    if($statusmsg) { 
      echo $statusmsg; 
    }else{
       // unsafe or invalid string passed 
    }
}
```

Comment: And start validating user input before passing it to query!

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have followed your advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change here like this:

```
header('Location: /community/viewtopic.php?id=' . $topicid . '&status=success');
```

**viewtopic.php**

```
$statusmsg = $_GET['status'];
if (isset($statusmsg) && !empty($statusmsg)) {
    if ($statusmsg == "success") {
      $statusmsg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                      <strong>Success!</strong> Your post was submitted.
                    </div>';
    }else {
      $statusmsg = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: /community/viewtopic.php?id=' . $topicid . '+status=success');
```

Use '&' on the place of '+' in this line.You will able to get value of status passed in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `+` with `&` like this :

```
header('Location: /community/viewtopic.php?id=' . $topicid . '&status=success');
```

Now the `$_GET['status']` catch the status value